# Handlebars Scope Issue: Can't access template variable from embedded `each`

Tags: javascript, html, templates, handlebars.js, keystonejs

I am trying to figure out why I can't access my template variables from within an embedded `each` statement in my handlebars template (rendered within my [keystone](http://keystonejs.com/) project). I have read numerous issues here on StackOverflow with similar problems, but none of them solved my particular use case.

I have a simple data object that gets passed to the Handlebars template that looks [roughly] like this:

```
{ 
   rootPath: '../../../', 
   navigation: { all: { 'a': { sublinks: [Object] }
}
```

### My question is:

Why does the `rootPath` template variable print perfectly in `{{#each navigation.all}}`, but inaccessible from within `{{#each sublinks}}`?

Here is my Handlebars template:

```
<!-- rootPath prints fine here -->
Here is your rootPath variable: {{rootPath}}

{{#each navigation.all}}

    <!-- rootPath prints fine here -->
    top-level rootPath: {{../rootPath}}

    {{#if sublinks}}

            {{#each sublinks}}

                <!-- WHY WON'T ROOTPATH PRINT HERE?? -->
                <!-- Obviously, I am trying the three possible scope paths -->
                sub-level rootPath attempt 1: {{../../rootPath}}
                sub-level rootPath attempt 2: {{../rootPath}}
                sub-level rootPath attempt 3: {{rootPath}}

            {{/each}}

    {{/if}}

{{/each}}
```

I get the following output *(notice how all the sub-level attempts don't have access to the `rootPath` template variable)*:

```
Here is your rootPath variable: ../../../
top-level rootPath: ../../../
sub-level rootPath attempt 1:
sub-level rootPath attempt 2:
sub-level rootPath attempt 3:
```

**What I need is for the `rootPath` to be available everywhere, so I can get something like this:**

```
Here is your rootPath variable: ../../../
top-level rootPath: ../../../
sub-level rootPath: ../../../
```

**So what scoping issue or syntax am I missing here?**

I am using Handlebars version `2.0.0`, as that is what comes pre-packaged by [keystone](http://keystonejs.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using the `@root` token.

Simply calling `@root.rootPath` from within the embedded `{{#each sublinks}}` was enough to solve my problem.

**Here is the correct template markup:**

```
Here is your rootPath variable: {{rootPath}}

{{#each navigation.all}}

    top-level rootPath 1: {{../rootPath}}      <!-- works -->
    top-level rootPath 2: {{@root.rootPath}}   <!-- works -->

    {{#if sublinks}}

            {{#each sublinks}}
                sub-level rootPath 1: {{@root.rootPath}}  <!-- works -->
                sub-level rootPath 2: {{../../rootPath}}  <!-- doesn't work -->
            {{/each}}

    {{/if}}

{{/each}}
```

**Which yields the following output:**

```
Here is your rootPath variable: ../../../
top-level rootPath 1: ../../../
top-level rootPath 2: ../../../
sub-level rootPath 1: ../../../
sub-level rootPath 2:
```

**Note:** for the top-level rootPath (in `{{#each navigation.all}}`, I could use either one of these:

```
{{../rootPath}}      <!-- works -->
{{@root.rootPath}}   <!-- works -->
```

**However**, from within the embedded `{{#each sublinks}}`, only the `@root.rootPath` seemed to work:

```
{{@root.rootPath}}  <!-- works -->
{{../../rootPath}}  <!-- doesn't work -->
```